# Difference between deleting child gameobjects from the hierarchy manually and by code in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a minesweeper game and i have added a button to generate a new "map". the problem is that the tiles can't tell how many mines are beside them after generating a new map (they can tell it on the initial generation).
Here is my code for generating a map:

```
void GenerateMines()
    {
        RowCount = 1;
        ColumnCount = 1;
        tempNumber = 0;
        IdSet = 0;
        //Generates random numbers equal to the amount of mines and adds it to the MineIds_ list
        for (int i = 0; i < AmountOfMines; i++)
        {
            do
            {
                tempNumber = Random.Range(0, AmountOfTiles);

            }
            while (MineIds_.Contains(tempNumber));
            {
                MineIds_.Add(tempNumber);
            }
        }
        //Instantiates all mines and puts a mine on the ones that are listed in the MineIds_ list, it also names the tiles according to which row and column they are in.
        for (int i = 0; i < AmountOfTiles; i++)
        {
            GameObject tile_ = Instantiate(tile, transform);
            tile_.GetComponent<tileProperties>().id = IdSet;
            tile_.GetComponent<tileProperties>().RowNumber = RowCount;
            tile_.GetComponent<tileProperties>().ColumnNumber = ColumnCount;
            tile_.name = RowCount + " " + ColumnCount;
            //mine assigning
            if (MineIds_.Contains(IdSet))
            {
                tile_.GetComponent<tileProperties>().hasMine = true;
            }
            IdSet++;
            ColumnCount++;

            if (GetComponent<GridLayoutGroup>().constraintCount < ColumnCount)
            {
                ColumnCount = 1;
                RowCount++;
            }

        }
        //tells the tiles with mines on them to add to the adjacentMines counter on the tiles beside them
        RowCount = 1;
        ColumnCount = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < AmountOfTiles; i++)
        {
            GameObject currentTile = GameObject.Find(RowCount + " " + ColumnCount);

            if (currentTile.GetComponent<tileProperties>().hasMine == true)
            {
                SendMineData();
            }
            ColumnCount++;

            if (GetComponent<GridLayoutGroup>().constraintCount < ColumnCount)
            {
                ColumnCount = 1;
                RowCount++;
            }
        }
    }
```

And here is the code I use to set the AdjacentMines counter for each tile:

```
//this is only triggered if the tile has a mine on it, it finds the 8 tiles next to it and incerases their AdjacentMines counter by 1
public void SendMineData()
    {
        int ColumnPointer;
            int RowPointer;
            ColumnPointer = ColumnCount;
            RowPointer = RowCount;

            ColumnPointer--;
            GameObject tileOnPointer = GameObject.Find(RowPointer + " " + ColumnPointer);
            if (tileOnPointer != null)
            {
                tileOnPointer.GetComponent<tileProperties>().AdjacentMines++;
            }
            RowPointer--;
            GameObject tileOnPointer2 = GameObject.Find(RowPointer + " " + ColumnPointer);
            if (tileOnPointer2 != null)
            {
                tileOnPointer2.GetComponent<tileProperties>().AdjacentMines++;
            }

            ColumnPointer++;
            GameObject tileOnPointer3 = GameObject.Find(RowPointer + " " + ColumnPointer);
            if (tileOnPointer3 != null)
            {
                tileOnPointer3.GetComponent<tileProperties>().AdjacentMines++;
            }
            ColumnPointer++;
            GameObject tileOnPointer4 = GameObject.Find(RowPointer + " " + ColumnPointer);
            if (tileOnPointer4 != null)
            {
                tileOnPointer4.GetComponent<tileProperties>().AdjacentMines++;
            }
            RowPointer++;
            GameObject tileOnPointer5 = GameObject.Find(RowPointer + " " + ColumnPointer);
            if (tileOnPointer5 != null)
            {
                tileOnPointer5.GetComponent<tileProperties>().AdjacentMines++;
            }
            RowPointer++;
            GameObject tileOnPointer6 = GameObject.Find(RowPointer + " " + ColumnPointer);
            if (tileOnPointer6 != null)
            {
                tileOnPointer6.GetComponent<tileProperties>().AdjacentMines++;
            }
            ColumnPointer--;
            GameObject tileOnPointer7 = GameObject.Find(RowPointer + " " + ColumnPointer);
            if (tileOnPointer7 != null)
            {
                tileOnPointer7.GetComponent<tileProperties>().AdjacentMines++;
            }
            ColumnPointer--;
            GameObject tileOnPointer8 = GameObject.Find(RowPointer + " " + ColumnPointer);
            if (tileOnPointer8 != null)
            {
                tileOnPointer8.GetComponent<tileProperties>().AdjacentMines++;
            }
    }
```

And Here is tho code i use for when the "generate new map" button is pressed:

```
public void GenerateNewMap()
    {
// Destroys all tiles
        foreach (Transform child in map.transform)
        {
            Destroy(child.gameObject);
        }
        MineIds_.Clear();
 //Generates new set of tiles
        GenerateMines();
    }
```

The problem is the following: If i press the "Generate new map button" the tiles will generate normally but the adjacentMines counter will be set to 0 on each tile. But when i Delete all the tiles manually from the hierarchy during runtime and then press the button it all works perfectly.

Comment: `Find` is quite expensive! Also `Destroy` is delayed and only happening actually at the end of the frame -> maybe `Find` returns the wrong objects ... Anyway why not instead of relying on string (= slow and error prone) rather use an actual map like `tileProperties[,] tiles = new tile properties[width, height];` and rather directly access your according tiles via e.g. `tiles[3,2].hasMine` etc

Answer (score 0):

In C#, you're not supposed to modify a collection when using a foreach loop.
Use a for loop instead. Further, the Destroy doesn't happen immediately.
I'm not quite sure of the timing, but it takes at least one frame before the Destroy starts processing. So the loop you invoke Destroy happens say in frame 0, while the destruction actually starts happening in frames starting at 1, and may not complete within the next frame. At least that's been my experience.

Answer (score 0):

There should not be a difference, the bug likely does not come from this.

The Destroy method is not immediate! That might be related. There is a delay between the call and the actual destruction, which might not exist when deleting in the scene. This could cause a timing issue with the current tiles being destroyed after the new ones are created.

You are also using GameObject.Find (which btw is slow) to find neighbors, but this technique is dependant on the scene names etc. which might be also related.
What you could do is store a bi-dimensional array of GameObject references as the map. Each tile can then access this array to know what objects are its neighbors. You can populate the array quite easily in your `GenerateMines` method, and clean it when you destroy the objects.